# Dynamic HTML buttons within the scope of Javascript ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm currently populating an HTML table to display users. I use calls to an API to serve my user data to the table, and Javascript to append the row to the table. The last entry in each row features a delete button, which is supposed to pass user data as a $put to a separate API endpoint to delete the user of the corresponding row:

```
//Existing adhoc-users table.
var adhocUsersHtml = "<div><table class='table table-striped'><tr><th>Section</th><th>Role</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th></tr>";
$.each(json.sections, function (index, section) {
    $.each(section.enrollments, function(index, user) {
        if (user.adhocEnrollment == true) {
            adhocUsersHtml += "<tr><td>" + section.sectionTitle + "</td><td>" + user.roleName + "</td><td>" + user.firstName + "</td><td>" + user.lastName + "</td>"
                + "<td><button id='delete' class='btn btn-default' data-style='height: 30px; margin-top: 0;'>Delete</button></td></tr>";
        }
    });
});
adhocUsersHtml += "</table></div>";
return adhocUsersHtml;
```

What's the best pattern for scoping 'this' with the delete buttons?

Should I put a custom attribute on the button that holds the user id for that row, and then add an onClick to all delete buttons that grabs the id and preforms the $put?

Is it possible to add an onClick function right after declaring HTML before appending it to the DOM with Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the user id into a data attribute on the delete button and add a single event handler to the table to handle all delete button clicks.

```
<button class='delete-user-btn' data-id="myUserId">Delete</button>

$("#myTable").on("click", ".delete-user-btn", function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
  //delete code goes here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

firstly, you are going to have many buttons so attribute **id='delete'** isn't appropiate

I will put class "delete" instead without userId and register onClick Listener after all buttons rendered
and since each row represent a user, i will put id on each row

```
<tr data-val="{userID}">
    ....
    <td><button class='btn btn-default delete' data-style='height: 30px; margin-top: 0;'>Delete</button></td>
</tr>

<script>$('.delete').on('click', function(e) {
 var tr = $(e.target).closest('tr'),
 id = tr.data('val')
 ... do your code
})</script>
```